# Java Logging in JSP File

Tags: java, jsp, java.util.logging

```
Logger logger = Logger.getGlobal(); 
FileHandler fh = new MyHandler("d:\\logging\\logging.log", true); 
logger.addHandler(fh);
fh.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());
logger.info("This is Test Info");
fh.close();
```

I have above code in sample JSP File. Do I need to repeat all above steps (attach handler, close handler) every time on each JSP to write log into logging.log

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to repeat all above steps (attach handler, close handler) every time on each JSP to write log into logging.log

No.  State modification of the logger such as adding handlers should be done outside of your program. Configuration is covered in the [logging guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a1.8) and most servlet containers allow you to either replace or modify the existing logging.properties file.  Consult your servlet container documentation for how that is done.

If you really want your application to configure the logger then create a [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to install your handler on startup and uninstall your handler on shutdown.